# Got JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json

Code:

```
import streamlit as st
import json
import requests
import numpy as np

URI = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000'

st.title('Newral Network Visualizer')
st.sidebar.markdown('## Input image')

if st.button('Get random prediction'):
    response = requests.post(URI, data={})
    response = json.loads(response.text)
```

Output:

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Traceback:

```
 File "c:\users\niloy\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\streamlit\ScriptRunner.py", line 322, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
 File "C:\Users\Niloy\Downloads\Digit classifier with flask\app.py", line 14, in <module>
    response = json.loads(response.text)
 File "c:\users\niloy\anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
 File "c:\users\niloy\anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
 File "c:\users\niloy\anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
```

Comment: 1) Code that comes *after* the error is irrelevant to the issue and should not be included here 2) question is about `json`, and has nothing to do with `machine-learning`, `tensorflow` (which you don't seem to use at all, and `ml` (which tag is not about machine learning - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file is not json formatted. If you try to read json values from a file you have to do it like that:
import json

```
import json
file = 'filename.txt'
with open(file,'r') as f:
    x = json.load(f)
    print(x)
```